# Excel RefreshAll using powershell script along with credentials

Tags: excel, powershell, refresh, credentials, windows-security

I need to refresh an excel using Powershell script (so that I can later schedule it in task scheduler). This refresh requires credentials to be entered. Does anyone know of a way to pass these credentials from the powershell script? The excel hangs at RefreshAll() for the user to enter the credentials.

Comment: share the code.  what do you mean by refresh. Are you trying to reload the file?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the pscredential object to provide the credentials. 
It is possible to store it to a file (encrypted).

[save PSCredential in the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029235/save-pscredential-in-the-file)

Might be what you are looking for.