# How can connect to sql server from Powershell without password?

Tags: sql, powershell

My network 10.10.10.0/24

The SQL server is in other network and other domain. I connect to it via vpn

IP address sql 192.168.1.1

I have access only sql without RDP

I try to connect to SQL server from Powershell.

```
invoke-dbaquery -SQLInstance 192.168.1.1 -sqlcredential 'sa' -query "select @@servername"
```

Work fine but appear a window so that input password. If we input the password then command work and output sql verssion.

How can do so that work without input the password?

Comment: `-SqlCredential` accepts a credentials object i.e. it's supports more than a username. Check out `New-DbaCredential`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to export your credential to a file using the below cmdlets. (One-time process)

```
$Cred = Get-Credential -Credential "sa"
$Cred | Export-Clixml -Path "C:\Temp\SQLCred.cred"
```

And then you can import the credential file and use it in your script whenever you want.

```
$Cred = Import-Clixml -Path "C:\Temp\SQLCred.cred"

Invoke-DbaQuery -SQLInstance 192.168.1.1 -sqlcredential $Cred -query "select @@servername"
```

Note: The exported credential will be fully encrypted and can be used only in your machine

Answer (score 0):

To use integrated security, simply omit the `-sqlcredential` part. Like so,

```
invoke-dbaquery -SQLInstance 192.168.1.1 -query "select @@servername"
```

In case you can't use integrated authentication (no domain trust or whatever), use PSCredential object to store and the credentials. Like so,

```
$cred = get-credential -credential 'sa'
invoke-dbaquery -SQLInstance 192.168.1.1 -query "select @@servername" -SqlCredential $cred
```

If you want to save the password in a file (mind the security issues though!), one can use [Export-Clixml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40029496/503046) to store and retrieve the credential object.

Comment: Thank you for your help