# How to copy a file from local work space to remote server (not a network shared path) with powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs, powershell-remoting, vnext

I am trying to copy a file from my local workspace to a remote server (not a network shared path) by using the powershell command through Inline Powershell" task in TFS vNext build definition.
FYI, destination path is not a network shared path

I tried with below commands

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "remote server name" -Credential "domain\username" 
Copy-Item "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Test.htm" -Destination "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\" -ToSession $Session
```

But it's promoting for the password every time and I tried with entering the password manually and the result looks good.

How can we achieve this step without prompting password or credentials

Comment: You should put your credentials into a PSCredential object before passing it to `New-PSSession`. See [Static Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55065136/invoke-command-with-static-password/55065520#55065520) for how to create a pscredential object (`$credential`). Then just pass that variable to your command `-Credential $Credential`.

Comment: Do you have to enter creds to create a remote session on the target server?

Comment: Thank you @AdminOfThings for your quick response and issue got resolved.

Comment: Why are you not using the Windows Machine File Copy task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it's not on a network share? :)

Powershell only takes password as a secure string. You can use `$credential = Get-Credential` to render a really cool box to store those credentials for you, or if you want to store your login programmatically (not recommended for obvious security reasons) use this:

```
$passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "<password>" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("<username>",$passwd)
```

There might be a way to inherit your current domain credentials, but that's way beyond me, and a quick google search turns up nothing.

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to post the whole thing:

```
$passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "<password>" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("<username>",$passwd)
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "remote server name" -Credential $credential
Copy-Item "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Test.htm" -Destination "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\" -ToSession $Session
```