# correct syntax for putting a powershell script into a variable with double quotes

Tags: powershell, powercli, sqlps

I have a need to put a PowerShell script into a variable with double quotes like so. However I am not aware of the correct syntax for this as I see syntax errors with $script variable when I try this.

```
$script = "Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {Import-Module sqlserver; invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Using:hostname\MSSQLServer; invoke-sqlcmd "create login [$Using:sqluser] from windows";invoke-sqlcmd "alter server role sysadmin add member [$Using:sqluser]"}"

$runscript = Invoke-VMScript -VM $vm -ScriptText $script -GuestUser $tmpl_user -GuestPassword $tmpl_pass -ToolsWaitSecs 300
```

Comment: Are you hoping to pass the script to `Invoke-VMScript` _as-is_? If so, use `'` single-quotes instead of double-quotes. If you need to have _some_ of the variables in the string expanded by PowerShell before invocation, you should keep the double-quotes, but make sure you escape the `$` in front of any variable that you _don't_ want PowerShell to expand

Answer (score 2):

[`Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText`](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/powercli/latest/vmware.vimautomation.core/commands/invoke-vmscript/#Default) accepts only a *string* containing PowerShell code, and has *no* support for separately passing *arguments* to that code.

The implications are:

- **In order to include variable values from the *caller*'s scope you indeed need to use *string interpolation*** (via an *expandable string*, `"..."`), as you have attempted.

  - Note that this situationally requires *embedded quoting* around reference to caller variables whose values may contain *spaces* or other special characters; e.g.
    `"... -Foo '$foo' ..."`)
- As [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out, **variable references you want to be evaluated on the *target* machine must have their `$` sigil escaped as `` `$ ``** so as to prevent premature interpolation on the caller's side; e.g. `` `$Using:sqluser ``

There's a **catch**, however:

- **Use of string interpolation imposes limits on *what data types* may be embedded in the string**, as not all data types have *string*-literal representations that are recognized as the original type.

  - In your case, the caller-side `$cred` variable contains **a [`[PSCredential]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSCredential) instance, which does *not* stringify meaningfully** (and cannot, for security reasons): it meaninglessly expands to a verbatim string value of `System.Management.Automation.PSCredential`, i.e. the instance's *type name*.
    In other words: **you cannot pass credentials this way**.
  - A **potential workaround requires *up-front* work on the *target* machine**: You can try to save the credentials in encrypted form to a file and then deserialize that file at invocation time via [`Import-Clixml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-clixml).

    - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40029496/45375) for a demonstration, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55797281/45375) for the security implications of this approach.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try a few options that you noted.