# Passing admin credentials in Start-Process cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I am trying to build a script that installs an application with encrypted local admin credentials on the pc when the user logged in is not an admin.

I am running the below cmdlet:

```
$User = "admin@domain.com" 
$PasswordFile = "C:\temp\Cred\Password.txt" 
$KeyFile = "C:\temp\Cred\AES.key" 
$key = Get-Content $KeyFile 
$MyCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, (Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key) 

Start-Process -FilePath C:\Temp\7z2301-x64.exe -Credential $MyCredential
```

However, I am getting below error even though I am passing correct credentials:

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The user name or 
password is incorrect.
At line:13 char:1
+ Start-Process -FilePath C:\Temp\7z2301-x64.exe -Credential $MyCredent ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOp 
   erationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.C 
   ommands.StartProcessCommand
```

Can someone please help on this?

Thank you in advance!

Getting error invalid username and password when running above code.

Comment: The error message appears to explain the problem. How did you create the credential file?

Answer (score 0):

If the account you’re using doesn’t have the necessary permissions to access the current directory, you might encounter this error.

If you’re running your script as a service, the service might be running under a different account that doesn’t have the necessary permissions.

Try `Get-Credential` to confirm the credentials are working properly.

```
$MyCredential = Get-Credential
Start-Process -FilePath C:\Temp\<some_exe>.exe -Credential $MyCredential
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried the above code but still getting the same error.

Comment: First ensure the credentials are correct and have the necessary permissions, then try exporting the credential to a file and let me know if that works, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029235/save-pscredential-in-the-file

Comment: Tried this as well just now but still the same error. The account that I am using is the local admin of my pc and the password is correct as well. Somehow it is not working from PowerShell.

Comment: Ok while I look into this can you see if this could be a good solution for you? Save your cred in credential manager and then you can use the credentials in powershell https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CredentialManager/2.0

Comment: How are you typing your credentials? I just tired in the format `domain\username` and that worked for me.

Comment: When I pass user@domain.com, I get incorrect username/password. However, when I try to pass domain\username, I get error:

Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The requested operation requires elevation.

Comment: Is PowerShell running as admin? If so that means the account does not have the necessary admin permissions.

Comment: Yes PS is running as admin. What permissions do I check more?

Comment: First check if you actually have admin permissions, use this 

`if ($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
    {
        Write-Host "Running as Administrator."
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Not running as Administrator."
    }`

Comment: If the above returns not running as admin, then you need to check your account with your AD admin and request/assign the correct permissions on your account.

Comment: The above check is giving me True. I have admin rights.

Comment: The user account used to *decrypt* the necessary password from a file **has to be the same user account** used *encrypt* it. And it has to be the same computer. You cannot use another user on another computer.  ☝‍♂️ What you try to accomplish will not work the way you want.